# MetaPost output an empty picture when using label

Tags: label, metapost

I'm trying to plot a simple graphic by **MetaPost** ,which comes along with the ***TexLive2013.iso*** .The code listed below is supposed to create an **oval** with some **label** .

```
beginfig(1);
a=.7in; b=.5in;
z0=(0,0);
z1=-z3=(a,0);
z2=-z4=(0,b);
draw z1..z2..z3..z4..cycle;
draw z1--z0--z2;
label.top("a", .5[z0,z1]);
label.lft("b", .5[z0,z2]);
dotlabel.bot("(0,0)", z0);
endfig;
end;
```

Howerver,when I opened the output flie **5.1** with **okular** ,it was blank.I opened the output file again with **kate**,listed below is the code:

```
%!PS
%%BoundingBox: -51 -37 51 37 
%%HiResBoundingBox: -50.64978 -36.25 50.64978 36.25 
%%Creator: MetaPost 1.802
%%CreationDate: 2013.09.08:1009
%%Pages: 1
%*Font: cmr10 9.96265 9.96265 61:8
%%BeginProlog
%%EndProlog
%%Page: 1 1
0 0 0 setrgbcolor 0 0.5 dtransform truncate idtransform setlinewidth pop
[] 0 setdash 1 setlinejoin 10 setmiterlimit
newpath 50.39978 0 moveto
50.39978 23.04858 25.56044 36 0 36 curveto
-25.56044 36 -50.39978 23.04858 -50.39978 0 curveto
-50.39978 -23.04858 -25.56044 -36 0 -36 curveto
25.56044 -36 50.39978 -23.04858 50.39978 0 curveto closepath stroke
1 setlinecap
newpath 50.39978 0 moveto
0 0 lineto
0 36 lineto stroke
22.70921 3 moveto
(a) cmr10 9.96265 fshow
showpage
%%EOF
```

If I comment

```
label.top("a", .5[z0,z1]);
label.lft("b", .5[z0,z2]);
dotlabel.bot("(0,0)", z0);
```

Then an oval without **label** can be seen.For all the codes above,**MetaPost** did not give any warning or error message.So the question is:

1. Why did my **MetaPost** output an empty graphic when using **label** ?
2. How to **fix** it ?

Comment: It seems that MetaPost is all right.I convert the ps graphics to pdf,and the pictures appears.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the MetaPost manual, chapter 3 (The MetaPost Workflow):

> If your graphics contain text labels, you might want to set variable
>   prologues to 3 to make sure the correct fonts are used under all
>   possible circumstances.

So, I added the following as the first line of your code:

```
prologues := 3;
```

What it essentially does here is embed the font into the output, which grows to ~20 Kbytes as a result.

After that, I can see the picture with labels in GSview. Without that, it complains like `Error: /undefined in cmr10`. Perhaps okular also had trouble locating fonts.